# Team Foundation Server - Increase Item Number of historicized Diagrams

Tags: tfs

is there a way to increase the limit of depictable items in a historicized diagram (like tests or bugs)? In our setup, it is hardcoded by Microsoft to a limit of 1000 items. Is there a file on the server where this limit can be changed?

[image: TFS error on the diagram lower left hand side]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? What's the meaning of historicized diagram? Do you mean task board?

Comment: I edited the original post and added a screen capture of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is by design. We can not change this limitation. Here is already a User voice, you can vote it:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/16438078-i-cannot-plot-in-a-chart-widget-a-query-with-more

Answer (score 0):

Generally we **do not recommend** to do actions against the TFS Databases.

However if you insist on changing the limitation, then you can run below sql query against the `Tfs_Configuration` database (You'd better backup the DBs first):

1. Open SSMS and connect to TFS SQL server
2. Navigate to the `Tfs_Configuration` DB -> Right Click  -> New Query
   -> Run below query:

`exec prc_SetRegistryValue 1, '#\Service\WorkItemTracking\Settings\MaxTrendChartTimeSliceResultSize\', 5000`

**Please note that change the limitation may affect the performance when using TFS**.

[image]